# initializing ADT in C

Tags: c, malloc

I've got the following ADT definition in my .h

```
struct BotStruct_t {
    int n_bots;
    char** nombre;
    char** caracter;
    int* fichas;
    int* carta_maxima;
};

typedef struct BotStruct_t * BotPtr_t;

int initBot(BotPtr_t bot);
```

And in the .c

```
int initBot(BotPtr_t bot) {
    bot = malloc(sizeof(struct BotStruct_t));
    if (bot == NULL) return 1;

    FILE* fp = fopen("/home/norhther/CLionProjects/blackjack/bot.txt","r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("El archivo de los bots no existe\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        char* line = NULL;
        size_t len = 0;
        getline(&line, &len, fp);
        int n_bots = atoi(line);
        bot->n_bots = n_bots;
        char** nombres_bots = malloc( sizeof(char*) * n_bots);
        char** caracter = malloc( sizeof(char*) * n_bots);
        int* fichas = malloc (sizeof (int) * n_bots);
        int* carta_maxima = malloc (sizeof (int) * n_bots);

        if (nombres_bots == NULL || caracter == NULL || fichas == NULL || carta_maxima == NULL) return 1;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < n_bots; i++) {
            getline(&line, &len, fp);
            nombres_bots[i] = strdup(line);
            getline(&line, &len, fp);
            fichas[i] = atoi(line);
            getline(&line, &len, fp);
            caracter[i] = strdup(line);
            getline(&line, &len, fp);
            carta_maxima[i] = atoi(line);
        }
        bot->nombre = nombres_bots;
        bot->caracter = caracter;
        bot->fichas = fichas;
        bot->carta_maxima = carta_maxima;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Finally my main

```
int main() {
    BotPtr_t bot;
    initBot(bot);
}
```

The problem here is that when I try to access to any element of bot, for instance, bot->carta_maxima[0] I get a SIGSEGV. If I try to do the same in the .c, inside the init function, it works. I really don't get it, because I'm working with the pointer and also doing the apporpiate malloc.
Any clues here?

Thanks!

Comment: The bot variable in the main never changes.  It starts as an uninitialized pointer and it has the same value after the call to initBot.  If you want the value to be accessible after the call to initBot, you should pass the address of bot in the main by doing: initBot(&bot) and have the declaration be initBot(BotPtr_t *bot) - including using *bot everywhere you are using bot now (in the initBot function).

Comment: or dont pass a pointer in and just return a bot pointer from the init function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be trying to return a pointer to your `BotStruct_t` via the init argument.  The problem is, in C all arguments are passed by -value-, so the pointer `bot` in the `initBot()` routine is local to that routine.

What you need to do is pass A POINTER TO a pointer to your `BotStruct_t`, so you can assign to the caller's version of the pointer via the pointer-to-pointer.  I.e change `BotPtr_t bot` to `BotPtr_t * pbot`, assign `*pbot = malloc(...)`, etc.